# Only 1 of 2 similar rewriteRule works

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

**:: 1.) Intro ::**

.htacces looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php)[^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php)[^/]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&keyword=$2&zip=$3&range=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php)[^/]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&keyword=$2&zip=$3&range=$4&action=$5 [L]

#ONLY 1 OF THIS RULES WORK -> ASK STACKOVERFLOW!
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php)[^/]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&ctitle=$2&cid=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php)[^/]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&ptitle=$2&pid=$3 [L]
```

Please have a look at the last two rules:

```
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php)[^/]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&ctitle=$2&cid=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php)[^/]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&ptitle=$2&pid=$3 [L]
```

These Rules will do the following things:

**Rewrite page1**
[*local or live environment url*]/index.php?page=**page1**&keyword=test&zip=12345&range=50

**to this:**
[*local or live environment url*]/**page1**/test/12345/50

---

**OR page2**
[local or live url here]/index.php?page=**page2**&keyword=test&zip=12345&range=50

**to this:**
[local or live url here]/**page2**/test/12345/50

**:: 2.) Problem ::**

Both rules don't work together because of the same count of expected url parameters, but the parameter names aren't the same

**:: 3.) Possible solution ::**

I could use universal parameter names for both pages so both pages simply use the same paremeters but I'm not sure if I once need different parameter names when I develop my project further and further.

**:: 4.) Desired solution ::**

I want to make the decision in each rewrite rule. An indikator could be the pagename. I tried some solutions but they don't work properly.
Where and how would I have to insert the pagename eg 'page1' and 'page2' so I can use both very similar reWriteRules?

**EDIT:**

NOTE: Panama Jack asked the right question here. The Pagename is not dynamic in this case.

Comment: The pattern is exactly the same for both rules. How is Apache supposed to know which one you want it to use?

Comment: THX for your feedback - Right! The pattern is the same, and thats why a ask about the pagename - did you read the whole question?

Comment: Are pages dynamic or is always page1 and page2?

Comment: always page1 or page2, in this case not dynamic. The start of the URL is dynamic - I use this rule for local testing and live environment.

Comment: Then that should be pretty easy. Just add the name of the pages directly in the pattern for each rule

Answer (score 1):

You rules can be as simple as this since the pages aren't dynamic. Probably most simple example.

```
RewriteRule ^page1/([^/]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&ctitle=$2&cid=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^page2/([^/]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&ptitle=$2&pid=$3 [L]
```

Comment: I'll try it ... not sure if this works, had a similar solution already. Thanks so far!

Comment: There's no reason it shouldn't really.

Comment: The rules do in fact work. So it's probably your implementation. What other rules do you have? Put these two rules first above other rule

Comment: see my answer above. I made a few changes in your solution so it works now

Comment: Oh well you changed the link, so yes the rule would have to change to. If it helped you, you can always accept or upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works for me now:

```
RewriteRule ^page1/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ page1&ctitle=$1&cid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^page2/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ page2&ptitle=$1&pid=$2 [L]
```

Any suggestions for improvement?